# Поиск минимальных значений ниже среднего

Tags: java

Приводится среднесуточная температура воздуха за месяц. Вывести номера тех дней, когда среднемесячная температура была ниже среднесуточной температуры. Количество дней в месяце определить по названию месяца.
Я тут кое как начала писать код, но оч сомневаюсь что он правильный.

```
public class Laba5_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n=0;
        int month = 12;
        String monthString;
        switch (month) {
            case 1:  monthString = "January";
                     break;
            case 2:  monthString = "February";
                     break;
            case 3:  monthString = "March";
                     break;
            case 4:  monthString = "April";
                     break;
            case 5:  monthString = "May";
                     break;
            case 6:  monthString = "June";
                     break;
            case 7:  monthString = "July";
                     break;
            case 8:  monthString = "August";
                     break;
            case 9:  monthString = "September";
                     break;
            case 10: monthString = "October";
                     break;
            case 11: monthString = "November";
                     break;
            case 12: monthString = "December";
                     break;
            default: monthString = "Invalid month";
                     break;
        }
        System.out.println(monthString);
        switch (month) {
        case 1: case 3: case 5:
        case 7: case 8: case 10:
        case 12:
            n= 31;
            break;
        case 4: case 6:
        case 9: case 11:
            n= 30;
            break;
        case 2:
            n=28;}
        System.out.println("Введите название месяца");

        System.out.println("Введите температуру за день");
        for (int n = 0; n < 31; n++) {

            array[i] = input.nextInt();
            }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то сначала в консоль нужно ввести месяц? Если да, то:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaLab {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int days = 0, allTemperature = 0;
        boolean correct;
        String monthString = "";
        int[] temperature;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите название месяца");

        //будем требовать ввести название месяца до тех пор, 
        //пока не будет введен корректно
        do {
            correct = false;
            //можно вводить в любом регистре
            monthString = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            switch (monthString) {
                case "ЯНВАРЬ":  days = 31;
                    break;
                case "ФЕВРАЛЬ":  days = 28;
                    break;
                case "МАРТ":  days = 31;
                    break;
                case "АПРЕЛЬ":  days = 30;
                    break;
                case "МАЙ":  days = 31;
                    break;
                case "ИЮНЬ":  days = 30;
                    break;
                case "ИЮЛЬ":  days = 31;
                    break;
                case "АВГУСТ":  days = 31;
                    break;
                case "СЕНТЯБРЬ":  days = 30;
                    break;
                case "ОКТЯБРЬ": days = 31;
                    break;
                case "НОЯБРЬ": days = 30;
                    break;
                case "ДЕКАБРЬ": days = 31;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Название месяца некорректно!");
                    //TRUE даст возможность при ошибке возобновить запрос месяца
                    correct = true;
                    break;
            }
        }while (correct);
        System.out.println("Месяц: " + monthString.toUpperCase());
        System.out.println("Количество дней: " + days);
        System.out.println("Введите температуру за день");
        //инициализировали массив полученным месяцем
        temperature = new int[days];
        //заполним месяц
        for (int i = 0; i < days; i++) {
            System.out.println("День №: " + (i+1));
            temperature[i] = sc.nextInt();
            //"складываем" общую сумму температур для получения в дальнейшем средней
            allTemperature += temperature[i];
        }
       //пройдем по массиву и сравним каждый день с
        for (int i = 0; i < temperature.length; i++){
            if ((allTemperature / days) < temperature[i]) {
                System.out.println("Среднемесячная температура: " + (allTemperature / days) + "Сº");
                System.out.println("Температура выше суточной была в: " + (i+1) + " день = " + temperature[i] + "Сº");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод такой:

```
Среднемесячная температура: 4Сº
Температура выше суточной была в: 1 день = 6Сº
Среднемесячная температура: 4Сº
Температура выше суточной была в: 3 день = 8Сº
Среднемесячная температура: 4Сº
Температура выше суточной была в: 5 день = 5Сº
Среднемесячная температура: 4Сº
Температура выше суточной была в: 6 день = 8Сº
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Main
{
    // Перечисление месяцев
    enum Month
    {
        January,
        February,
        March,
        April,
        May,
        June,
        July,
        August,
        September,
        October,
        November,
        December
    }

    private static Month _month = Month.January; // объявление перечисления 
    private static float[][] _monthTemp = new float[12][31]; // двумерный массив под темературы
    private static boolean _firstRun = false; // флаг-первый запуск

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        GenerateTemp(); // первичная генерация температурных данных
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Запуск в цикле
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Доступные команды:");
            System.out.println("all - получить информацию о всех месяцах");
            System.out.println("generate - выполнить генерацию новых значений для дней и месяцев");
            System.out.println("month НазваниеМесяца - показать информацию за конкретный месяц");
            System.out.println("exit - выйти из программы");
            String input = in.nextLine(); // получаем текст
            String[] command = input.split(" "); // разбиваем его на подстроки
            // Определяем, что будем делать с введенным текстом 
            switch (command[0])
            {
                case "all":
                {
                    InfoAllTemp(); // получаем информацию за все месяца сразу
                }
                break;
                case "generate":
                {
                    GenerateTemp(); // генерируем данные по темературе по новому
                }
                break;
                case "month":
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Month _temp = _month.valueOf(command[1]);
                        GetMonthInfo(_temp.ordinal()); // получаем информацию только об одном месяце
                    }
                    catch(RuntimeException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Название месяца введено некорректно!\nПожалуйста, повторите ввод!");
                    }
                }
                break;
                case "exit":
                {
                    System.exit(0); // выходим из программы
                }
                break;
                default:
                {
                    System.out.println("Введенной команды не существует\nПовторите ввод снова!");
                }
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void GetMonthInfo(int month)
    {
        Month temp[] = Month.values();
        // Выводим информацию за месяц
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Месяц: " + temp[month].toString());
        System.out.println("Количество дней: " + GetDayCount(month));
        System.out.println("Средняя температура: " + GetMediumTemp(month));
        System.out.println("Дневная температура, ниже среднемесячной:");
        for (int countDay = 0; countDay < GetDayCount(month); countDay++)
        {
            if (_monthTemp[month][countDay] < GetMediumTemp(month))
            {
                System.out.println(countDay+1 + " числа" + ": " + _monthTemp[month][countDay]);
            } 
        }
        System.out.println("\nДневная температура, выше среднемесячной:");
        for (int countDay = 0; countDay < GetDayCount(month); countDay++)
        {

            if (_monthTemp[month][countDay] > GetMediumTemp(month))
            {
                System.out.println(countDay+1 + " числа" + ": " + _monthTemp[month][countDay]);
            } 
        }
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
    }

    public static void GenerateTemp()
    {
        for (int countMonth = 0; countMonth < _monthTemp.length; countMonth++)
        {
            for (int countDay = 0; countDay < GetDayCount(countMonth); countDay++)
            {
                // Генерируем температуру по дням для всех дней каждого месяца
                // При необходимости, достаточно будет поменять эту строчку на пользовательский ввод
                _monthTemp[countMonth][countDay] = 10 + (float)(Math.random() * ((30 - 10)));

            }
        }
        // Блок не допускает вывода строки при первом запуске 
        if (!_firstRun)
        {
            _firstRun = true;
        } else
        {
            System.out.println("Генерация новых значений завершена!\n");

        }
    }

    public static void InfoAllTemp()
    {
            Month temp[] = Month.values();
            // Вывод информации за все месяцы
            for (int countMonth = 0; countMonth < _monthTemp.length; countMonth++)
            {
                System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Месяц: " + temp[countMonth].toString());
                System.out.println("Количество дней: " + GetDayCount(countMonth));
                System.out.println("Средняя температура: " + GetMediumTemp(countMonth));
                System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
            }
    }

    public static float GetMediumTemp(int month)
    {
        float mediumTemp = 0;
        for (int countDay = 0; countDay < GetDayCount(month); countDay++)
        {
            // Суммируем температуры всех дней заданного месяца
            mediumTemp += _monthTemp[month][countDay] + 1; 
        }
        // Возвращаем среднее значение
        return mediumTemp / GetDayCount(month);
    }

    public static int GetDayCount(int month)
    {
        int day = 0;
        Month temp[] = Month.values();
        // Получаем число дней в месяце
        switch(temp[month].toString())
            {
                case "April":
                case "June":
                case "September":
                case "November":
                day = 30;
                break;
                case "February":
                day = 28;
                break;
                default:
                day = 31;
                break;
            }
        return day;
    }
}
```

P.S. Не имею под рукой Java-SDK, выполнял на https://ideone.com/4u291j, работает.